Golang server does not see host inside docker container
Docker container does not see 127.0.0.1 address
I have Golang code:
serverAddress := os.Getenv("SERVER_ADDRESS")
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    serverAddress,
    Handler: router,
}

if internalErr := server.ListenAndServe(); internalErr != nil {
    logger.Fatal("failed to start server", zap.Error(internalErr))
}

And I have Dockerfile:
FROM golang:1.22 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /match-bot cmd/match_bot/main.go

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11 AS build-release-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /match-bot /match-bot

ENV SERVER_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1:8080"

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/match-bot"]

After it I tried to do that:
docker build -t test . 
docker run -d --restart on-failure -p 8080:8080 --network=bridge test

But it does not work - I have the following error:
{"level":"fatal","ts":1719151000.4234245,"caller":"match_bot/main.go:99","msg":"failed to start server","error":"listen tcp: lookup = 127.0.0.1: no such host","stacktrace":"main.main.func1\n\t/app/cmd/match_bot/main.go:99"}

I have already tried localhost:8080, 0.0.0.0:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080, :8080

Have you tried hard-coding the address in your Go program? That might tell you if it's something to do with the environment variable. In a container, listening on the default port should be fine since you can map it to whatever you want on the host. So maybe you don't need the custom server config at all and can just go with the default? If you get it to work, then binding to 127.0.0.1 will cause your program to only accept connections from inside the container which is probably not what you want. You want to bind to all interfaces.

You have a blank space in your Dockerfile which is not supposed to be there:
ENV SERVER_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1:8080"

is supposed to read
ENV SERVER_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1:8080"

The way you have it, SERVER_ADDRESS evaluates to = 127.0.0.1:8080.
You can verify that by adding
logger.Debug("starting server", zap.Strings("env", os.Environ()))

After changing the directive, your code should work. Also, it is important to sanitize your input, no matter how trivial the input may seem. Remember, SERVER_ADDRESS could be overwritten at deploy time.
This should do the trick
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

var validate *validator.Validate = validator.New()

func main() {

    logger, _ := zap.NewDevelopment()
    serverAddress := os.Getenv("SERVER_ADDRESS")

    if err := validate.Var(serverAddress, "required,hostname_port"); err != nil {
        logger.Fatal("invalid server address", zap.String("serverAddress", serverAddress), zap.Error(err))
    }

    logger.Debug("starting server", zap.Strings("env", os.Environ()))
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr: serverAddress,
    }

    if internalErr := server.ListenAndServe(); internalErr != nil && internalErr != http.ErrServerClosed {
        logger.Fatal("failed to start server", zap.Error(internalErr))
    }
}

